# C++ Execute a command line and get Result.

Tags: c++, cmd, command, line, popen

I need some help with my situation. I want to execute a Terminal and get the Result. I have done it so far, but i want to do some other Commands after getting the Result. My Problem is, that everytime when i do a command, the console restarts, and i dont know how to write in a active prozess.

I have done it like that:

```
FILE *fp = popen(r.c_str(),"r");
    char buf[2560];

    while (fgets(buf, 2560, fp))
    {
        s->SendLine(buf);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

I want to "send" another command in the same process. How can i do that?

Comment: Are you saying you you do some action in the console, then the program ends but you want it to continue to carry out more commands?

Comment: What is "a Terminal"? What is "the Result"? What is "other Commands"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question and comment. It sounds like you want your program to run in a loop until the user chooses to close it. You will want something like this:

```
bool keepProgramOpen = true;
public void main()
{       
    while(keepProgramOpen)
    {
        printf("Choose and option\n");
        printf("Option 1: press 1\n");
        printf("Option 2: press 2\n"); //etc
        char result = getchar();

        switch result
        {
            //code to select which option was picked
            case 1:
                fileFunction();
                break;
            case 2:
                someOtherFunction();
                break;
            case 3:
                closeProgram(); //set keepProgramOpen false in here to end program
                break;
            //etc
        }
    }
}

fileFunction()
{
   FILE *fp = popen(r.c_str(),"r");
   char buf[2560];

   while (fgets(buf, 2560, fp))
   {
       s->SendLine(buf);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Not really, it should stay in one process. 
Example.
When R would be ="dir" 
it would show mit the right path. 
next R could be ="cd .."
but it wouldnt affect the next command... hope ure able to understand :$

Comment: So are you talking about command line parameters you enter when calling the program, or ones you enter after the program has started. You might want to re-phrase your question and include more of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think before `fclose(fp)` use `r2` as

```
fputs(r2.c_str(),fp)
```